# Can create a "frozen" windows 10 user?

Tags: windows-10

I'm configuring computers for a library and I need every time computers are restarted all the programs, file are delated. There are programs like deep freeze, but is there any way to do this with Windows configuration? It's like when you went to the cybercafé and turned off your computer and erased everything you had saved from the previous person who was playing.

Comment: Perhaps Desired State Configuration?

Comment: Perhaps [Reboot Restore Rx](https://horizondatasys.com/reboot-restore-rx-freeware/) or even [multi-app kiosk mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps)?

Comment: Yes, maybe with the kiosk configuration it works, I'm going to try it and I'll tell you